# Upload video to YouTube with CURL and API v3

Tags: api, video, upload, youtube

This is the function that I am using:

```
function uploadVideo($file, $title, $description, $tags, $categoryId, $privacy, $tokenacc){
$direccionvideo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploadyt/mp4/'.$file;
$video->snippet['title']         = $title;
$video->snippet['description']   = $description;
$video->snippet['categoryId']   = $categoryId;
$video->snippet['tags']       = array($tags); // array

$video->status['privacyStatus'] = $privacy;

$res = json_encode($video);

$parms = array(
'part'  => 'snippet, status',
    'file'  => '@'.$direccionvideo,
    'body' => $res
);

$cabeceras = array('Authorization: Bearer '.$tokenacc, 'Content-Type: video/mp4');

$ch = curl_init('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,status&key=AIXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parms);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cabeceras);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $return;
}
```

But it returns this:

```
{ "kind": "youtube#video", "etag": "\"rFqCJSkEICLP3Hq6a4AADI7kf48/Ppz1_LDXz9KAv4eC-UouSKrhjn4\"", "id": "XXXXXXXXX", "snippet": { "publishedAt": "2013-07-15T03:06:45.000Z", "channelId": "UCWXN1EzwIl2clMliTxxO7ww", **"title": "unknown"**, **"description": ""**, "thumbnails": { "default": { "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XXXXXXXX/default.jpg" }, "medium": { "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XXXXXXXX/mqdefault.jpg" }, "high": { "url": "https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/XXXXXXXX/hqdefault.jpg" } }, "channelTitle": "ChannelYouTube", "categoryId": "2" }, "status": { "uploadStatus": "uploaded", "privacyStatus": "public", "license": "youtube", "embeddable": true, "publicStatsViewable": true } }
```

Upload a video (which you can not be processed) with the title "unknown", without description, tags and category.

It is as if the API does not take any post field.

Can anyone help?